# Native method not found error on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, jmonkeyengine

---

For my bachelor thesis iam trying developing a JmonkeyGame.
4 weeks ago i read something about use a Character and use Physics ==> use BetterCharacterControl class.
Now my problem is that as soon as i implement **statemanager.attach(bulletAppState)**:

```
@Override
public void simpleInitApp() {

    bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
    stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);

    initKeys();
    initMouse();
    initAudio();
    createLight();
    createTerrain();
    createSky();
    addPlayer();
    addCamera();
}
```

I get an error on android.
I am developing in eclipse, not JME3-Programm because the game is only a part of the apk.

Libaries in eclipse:
JME3-android.jar, JME3-bullet.jar, JME3-core.jar

I have no idea where to look for a solution, or why this problem occours.
Help or tips to my problem would be fabulous.

Hardware:
Sony Compact D5503
Android V. 4.4.2

Android Screenshot of error:

[image: http://i1259.photobucket.com/albums/ii554/hello12334/3_zps281973ea.png]

Comment: it seems it works now, don't know why, but it does.
i just compiled with JME sdk and copied all libraries out of the mobile folder to my eclipse lib folder.

Comment: hmmm cant edit anymore ...

it seems it works now, don't know why, but it does.

i just compiled with JME3SDK and copied all libraries out of the generated mobile folder to my eclipse lib folder and add to path ofcourse.

picture link:
http://i1259.photobucket.com/albums/ii554/hello12334/4_zps57f0be40.png

Maybe there is/will be another person with the same problem ;)